# Select from one table with count from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm doing a query where i select all from a table called employee and want to do a count of employee_id from two other tables and represent the count in 2 seperate columns.

**The tables:**

1. employee [id, etc.]
2. report [id, employee_id, etc.]
3. office_report[id, employee_id, etc.]

**What i did so far is:**

```
SELECT emp.*, COUNT(rep.id ) no_of_field_reports, COUNT(of_rep.id) no_of_office_reports 
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN report rep
    ON (emp.id = rep.employee_id) 
LEFT JOIN office_report of_rep 
    ON (emp.id = of_rep.employee_id) 
WHERE emp.user_id =7 AND emp.active = 1 
GROUP BY emp.id, emp.name 
ORDER BY emp.name ASC
```

The problem is, as soon as i have reports in BOTH report tables the count messes up. Say i have 16 reports in **report table** and 2 in **office_report** table, the count for **no_of_field_reports** and **no_of_office_reports** will become 32.

Im missing something obviously but as I'm not a SQL genius I can't figure out what.

Please make sure to explain what is causing the problem so I'm able to learn from my mistakes and get a better understanding of these type of queries as this is not going to be the last time.

I guess the answer will be the same for mariaDB, mySQL, and SQL in general so i added all those tag's for the sake of attention..

Comment: few options.  use distinct counts of the unique ID for each table or do the count as an inline view. THe reason the counts mess up is due to cardinality between the tables inflates the counts.

Comment: @xQbert adding DISTINCT to my SELECT does not seem to work .. I guess I'm doing it wrong ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly one approach if you're after distinct counts ( though you may need to adjust to the PK field)

```
SELECT emp.*, 
       COUNT(distinct rep.id ) no_of_field_reports, --may need to be on Unique key instead
       COUNT(distinct of_rep.id) no_of_office_reports --may need to be on Unique key instead)
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN report rep
    ON (emp.id = rep.employee_id) 
LEFT JOIN office_report of_rep 
    ON (emp.id = of_rep.employee_id) 
WHERE emp.user_id =7 AND emp.active = 1 
GROUP BY emp.id, emp.name 
ORDER BY emp.name ASC
```

An approach getting the counts before the joins if you're not after a distinct count then this is likely the right approach and offers flexibility.

```
SELECT emp.*, rep.cnt, of_Rep.cnt 
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(ID) cnt , employee_ID
           FROM REPORT 
           GROUP BY employee_ID) rep
  ON (emp.id = rep.employee_id) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(ID) cnt, Employee_ID      
          FROM office_report 
          GROUP BY employee_ID) of_rep 
  ON (emp.id = of_Rep.employee_id) 
WHERE emp.user_id =7 AND emp.active = 1 
GROUP BY emp.id, emp.name 
ORDER BY emp.name ASC
```

or use of correlated queries (but not supported all the time Such as when creating materialized views from this SQL)

```
SELECT emp.*, 
      (SELECT count(ID)
       FROM REPORT 
       WHERE  emp.id = rep.employee_id) Report_Cnt, 
      (SELECT count(ID)
       FROM office_report  of_REP
       WHERE emp.id = of_Rep.employee_id) of_Rep_Cnt
FROM employee emp
WHERE emp.user_id =7 AND emp.active = 1 
GROUP BY emp.id, emp.name 
ORDER BY emp.name ASC
```

Comment: Nice.. but why do I need to adjust the PK ?

Comment: I didn't know if the ID's were unique or PKs'... that's way I said you MAY need to adjust.  since they are PK's you should be fine.

Comment: The report id's are also unique .. so adjustment should not be needed right ?

Comment: If report.id and office-Report.id are pks then the 1st solution of using count(distinct ID) should work.