# Querying tables with count from other tables

Tags: sql-server, database, linq, sql-server-2008

I have three tables in database that are "UserGroup" which has a unique group for user. The second table is "Users" that has users but multiple users can belong to same usergroup.

Similarly I have a third table "Roles" that contains roles and multiple roles
can belong to same "usergroup".

Therefore parent table is UserGroup the id of this table is foreign key in two other tables.

A related question has been already asked here but if you can answer with my scenario , it would be better
[Select from one table with count from two other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660460/select-from-one-table-with-count-from-two-other-tables)

I am trying to query these tables such that I need count of "user Group" from
each of the two tables i.e from "users" and roles". If you can help with the Linq query, it would be appreciated.

For example:

"User Group Table"

```
Id GroupName
1   Admin
2   IT
3   Helpdesk
```

"Users Table"

```
Id USerGroupId UserName
1    1          Tom
2    1          Mickey
3    2          John
4    3          Sandy
```

"Roles Table"

```
Id  USerGroupId    Role
1     2            Supervisor 
2     2            Superidetendent
3     3            etc
4     3            etc
```

Output should show:

```
GroupName     USerCount    RolesCount
Admin           2            0
IT              1            2
Helpdesk        1            2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupName 
,(SELECT COUNT*) FROM Users U WHERE U.USerGroupId=G.Id) [USerCount]   
,(SELECT COUNT*) FROM Roles r WHERE R.USerGroupId=G.Id) [RolesCount]  
FROM Group g
```

Comment: you made the same mistake I did... LINQ query.

Comment: Hi, The above query is correct . could I get the linq version of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that should work:

```
UsersTable.GroupBy(u => u.USerGroupId).Select(group => new { 
                             USerGroupId = group.Key, 
                             Count = group.Count() 
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.USerGroupId);

RolesTable.GroupBy(u => u.USerGroupId).Select(group => new { 
                             USerGroupId = group.Key, 
                             Count = group.Count() 
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.USerGroupId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the linq to Entity in c# (if you use Entity Framework to connect to DB)

```
var query = 
    from h in (
        (from b in db.UserTable
        group b.UserGroup by new {
          b.UserGroup.GroupName
        } into g
        select new {
          g.Key.GroupName,
          UserCount = g.Count(p => p.GroupName != null)
        }))
    join k in (
        (from d in db.Roles
        group d.UserGroup by new {
          d.UserGroup.GroupName
        } into g
        select new {
          g.Key.GroupName,
          RolesCount = g.Count(p => p.GroupName != null)
        })) on h.GroupName equals k.GroupName into k_join
    from k in k_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
      h.GroupName,
      h.UserCount,
      RolesCount = k.RolesCount
    };
```

this is linq to SQL in c# (if you use DBML)

```
var query = 
        from h in (
            (from a in db.UserGroup
            join b in db.UserTable on new { Id = a.Id } equals new { Id = b.UserGroupId } into b_join
            from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group a by new {
              a.GroupName
            } into g
            select new {
              g.Key.GroupName,
              UserCount = g.Count(p => p.GroupName != null)
            }))
        join k in (
            (from d in db.Roles
            group d.UserGroup by new {
              d.UserGroup.GroupName
            } into g
            select new {
              g.Key.GroupName,
              RolesCount = g.Count(p => p.GroupName != null)
            })) on h.GroupName equals k.GroupName into k_join
        from k in k_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
          h.GroupName,
          h.UserCount,
          RolesCount = k.RolesCount
        };
```

this is the source SQL

```
SELECT h.GroupName, h.UserCount, k.RolesCount
FROM
(SELECT a.GroupName, count(a.GroupName) as UserCount
from UserGroup a
LEFT JOIN UserTable b on a.id = b.UserGroupId
group by a.GroupName) h
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT a.GroupName, count(a.GroupName) as RolesCount
from UserGroup a
INNER JOIN Roles d on a.id = d.UserGroupId
group by a.GroupName) k on h.GroupName = k.GroupName
```

Comment: I have checked query but it is not returning the correct result as for admin group , this query is returning 2 for both usercount and rolescount . for rolescount, it should return 0. Could you please help with this again.

Comment: @Sweetie i edited and corrected my answer. can you try

Comment: @Sweetie if i helped you, can you accept my answer?